# @OneToMany delete not wor

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables and these classes :

**Global history :**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HISTORY", nullable = true)
private History history;
```

and **history** a simple class.

I want to ***undrestand*** why when I try to **remove** a Global history I get this error :

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that you want to `DELETE` some records in your table which is in `Parent-Child relationship`.
Check whether you have a table in `Parent-Child relationship`. it's like when you have a table `Department` (let's say as `Parent table`, here you have all department unique IDs') and `Employees` table (let's say as `Child table` (Foreign key), here you have `department_id keys` from the `Department` table to which employees are belong). When you want to `Update OR Delete` `Parent table` and there are no `referential actions` then Database protecting `Child's table` data from these operations;

you can read also here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp